# using ini_set in php to enable zip decompression

Tags: php, zip, unzip, ini-set

Can't find anything on this one. I have a zip file on my server that doesn't openly support the zip_***() functions. DreamHost's support staff has said that I can modify the php.ini file to allow these… but I was wondering if there's just a ini_set() I can use to turn the zip decompression functions on.

Thanks a million!
-Joel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

zip's done via a module. It couldn't be a simple ini_set() to turn it on. If it's not installed in PHP by default, you'd need to use `dl()` to load the module at runtime. I can't see a shared hoster enabling this, as it'd allow anyone to load malicious libraries into the webserver process at will.

I think dreamhost might have been thinking of transparent gzip compression of PHP's output instead, which can be controlled via ini_set().

Comment: Marc, thank you so much for the insight. I've got a Virtual Private Server, so they're a little more lenient than a shared server. So I'd like to try and add the module at runtime then first - would you know where i can get that module? what it's called? :-/ I really do appreciate your help man.

Comment: If it's your server, try looking in the php extensions directory (the location should be in the php.ini and/or phpinfo() output. Most likely it's something like 'zip.so' or (zip.dll if you're on Windows), but that's just a guess.

Comment: system('unzip -o ' . $file);
worked like a BOSS! don't understand how though, but I'm not going to complain...

Comment: That's just invoking an external zip program. If it works, great, but be careful to clean up as you'll be leaving the unzipped files lying around.